# populate newly added textbox with last texbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I populate newly added *begin_date* textbox with last *end_date* ?

```
$('body').on('focus', ".dpicker", function () {
$(this).datepicker();
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ow0gsnvs/6/)*** here[image]

Comment: Can there be more than 2 .deleteRow blocks? I mean how many time you can add new form inputs?

Comment: @TienNguyen yeah it can be 10 or what client will want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this functional after more than one form addition

Add class to your *addItem* link

```
<a href="#" id="addItem" class="addItem">add</a>
```

Modify click handler so it will be able to listen for newly added links

```
$(document).on('click', '.addItem', function () {...}
```

And add input field value update on appending of new form block

```
$(document).on('click', '.addItem', function () {
    var last_date;
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            last_date = $('.deleteRow:last .formInput:last input').val();
            $("#editorRows").append(str);
            $('.deleteRow:last .formInput:first input').val(last_date);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/mandarin6b0/ow0gsnvs/9/

P.S. Try to get rid of multiple identical id. (i.e. id="#addItem")

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
 $("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(str);
            $(".deleteRow").find("input:first").val($("#endDate").val());
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.clone()` either way-

```
          success: function (html) {
                $("#editorRows").append($this.closest('.deleteRow').clone());
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ow0gsnvs/10/